# Can not return login.html

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I try to use `thymleaf` with `spring`. But I could not manage to return my login.html when I go to `/login`.

This is my controller:

```
@GetMapping("/login")
public String login() {
    return "/login";//i also tried return "login" or "login.html
}
```

This is security config:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {


        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password(passwordEncoder().encode("password")).roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("admin").password(passwordEncoder().encode("admin")).roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override//when I comment those method, it works
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
//                .csrf().disable()//i also enabled this but still same
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/about").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
```

this is login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
>
<head>
    <title>Spring Security Example </title>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">

    <div class="row" style="margin-top:20px">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-3">
            <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
                <fieldset>
                    <h1>Please Sign In</h1>

                    <div th:if="${param.error}">
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            Invalid username and password.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div th:if="${param.logout}">
                        <div class="alert alert-info">
                            You have been logged out.
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control input-lg"
                               placeholder="UserName" required="true" autofocus="true"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-lg"
                               placeholder="Password" required="true"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Sign In"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I wrote in the code as comment.

When I disable the method:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
```

I can go to login page.

But without disabling, I can only see string as `login` when i go to http://localhost:8080/login

Comment: What annotations are there on your controller class.

Comment: only ``RestController`` @M. Deinum

Comment: You must use `@Controller` not `@RestController` and you should return `login` not `/login`.

Answer (score 2):

As found out from the comments; You need to annotate your controller with `@Controller` instead of `@RestController`. This will tell spring to return a view.

Then `return: "login";` and you should be good.

Make sure your html pages are in src/main/resources or src/main/resources/templates.

I don't know if this will make a difference but in your securityConfig, after `.loginPage("login")` add `.loginProcessingUrl("/login")` and `.defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true);` maybe. the `.permitAll()` isn't necessairy I think.

Answer (score 0):

What is actually happening in `protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)` is , when a user tries to access url's with these patterns `("/user/**") , ("/admin/**")` (which you have mentioned in the above configure method) the method will check whether the user has required authority to access that particular url.
 In your case, to access `("/admin/**")` he/she should have admin role. If the current user is trying to access this url `("/admin/**")`has the admin role then he will be directed to the required page. In case if the user has no admin authority then he will be directed to your login page which is decribed using `.formLogin().loginPage("/login")` in your method. Hence if you want to access the login page with the existing code, you will have to change the url pattern in controller `@GetMapping("/login")` to one of this pattern`("/user/**") , ("/admin/**")`.
Above is the reason why your code is working fine when the `protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)` is commented.

Comment: Did you try this solution?

Answer (score -1):

You must configure your template engine

An example bean configuration:

```
    @Bean
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver(){
    // SpringResourceTemplateResolver automatically integrates with Spring's own
    // resource resolution infrastructure, which is highly recommended.
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    // HTML is the default value, added here for the sake of clarity.
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    // Template cache is true by default. Set to false if you want
    // templates to be automatically updated when modified.
    templateResolver.setCacheable(true);
    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(){
    // SpringTemplateEngine automatically applies SpringStandardDialect and
    // enables Spring's own MessageSource message resolution mechanisms.
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    // Enabling the SpringEL compiler with Spring 4.2.4 or newer can
    // speed up execution in most scenarios, but might be incompatible
    // with specific cases when expressions in one template are reused
    // across different data types, so this flag is "false" by default
    // for safer backwards compatibility.
    templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
    return templateEngine;
}
```

Comment: Spring Boot automatically configures Thymeleaf when detected on the classpath.

Comment: I added your resolver to my webconfig class which I put to this question. Only changed ``        templateResolver.setPrefix("/templates");`` but still same

Comment: (> But without disabling, I can only see string as login when i go to > http://localhost:8080/login) ====>



If the resolver is correctly configured ==>

Going to http://localhost:8080/login shouldn't return an string "login" 

Check your resolver configuration either  your pom or you can force spring boot with your own configuration 

the problem is not related to  the method`void configure(HttpSecurity http)` ...